# Scorched3d will not launch

Tags: software-installation

Scorched3d worked then stopped. Unistalled and reinstalled did not help. Running Ubuntu 16.04.04LTS. I think it was after installing new release.

I think the problem is the Ubuntu 16.04.4LTS. The newer version has no Scorched3d in the Ubuntu Software Center. I have 3 systems. After updating to new version. Scorched3D will not install and work after updating.

```
ron@RonsComputer:~$ sudo objdump -p $(type -p scorched3d) | grep NEEDED 
NEEDED libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0 
NEEDED libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0
NEEDED libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
NEEDED libfreetype.so.6
NEEDED libz.so.1
NEEDED libSDL-1.2.so.0
NEEDED libSDL_net-1.2.so.0
NEEDED libexpat.so.1 
NEEDED libstdc++.so.6
NEEDED libm.so.6
NEEDED libgcc_s.so.1
NEEDED libpthread.so.0
NEEDED libc.so.6
```

ron@ron-desktop ~ $ objdump -p $(type -p scorched3d) | grep NEEDED | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 dpkg -S 
libwxgtk3.0-0v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0.2.0
libwxgtk3.0-0v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0
libwxgtk3.0-0v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0.2.0
libwxgtk3.0-0v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0
libwxbase3.0-0v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0.2.0
libwxbase3.0-0v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
libfreetype6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1
libfreetype6:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
libfreetype6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
libfreetype6:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1
zlib1g:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
zlib1g:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
zlib1g:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
zlib1g:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
libsdl1.2debian:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
libsdl1.2debian:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
libsdl1.2debian:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
libsdl1.2debian:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
libsdl-net1.2:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_net-1.2.so.0
libsdl-net1.2:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL_net-1.2.so.0
libsdl-net1.2:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_net-1.2.so.0.8.0
libsdl-net1.2:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL_net-1.2.so.0.8.0
libexpat1:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
libexpat1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
libexpat1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
libexpat1:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
libstdc++6:amd64: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
libstdc++6:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
libstdc++6:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
libstdc++6:i386: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
libc6:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
libgcc1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc1:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libc6:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
libc6:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
ron@ron-desktop ~ $

Comment: Perhaps you're missing some libraries. In a Terminal, run `ldd $(type -p scorched3d)` and `objdump -p $(type -p scorched3d) | grep NEEDED`. Inspect the output for errors.

Comment: What is typed in (type -p scorched3d)

Comment: How do i get the items needed

Comment: Is there anybody out there that can get Scorched 3D. to run on newer versions of 16.04.4 Ubuntu. Can it be installed with the terminal

Comment: @https://askubuntu.com/users/611098/ron-barnish You type, exactly `ldd $(type -p scorched3d)`. Did you install all 3 of `scorched3d`, `scorched3d-data` and `scorched3d-dbg`? I did, and it worked for me. `sudo apt install scorched3d scorched3d-data scorched3d-dbg`

Comment: ron@RonsComputer:~$ sudo objdump -p $(type -p scorched3d) | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0
  NEEDED               libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0
  NEEDED               libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
  NEEDED               libfreetype.so.6
  NEEDED               libz.so.1
  NEEDED               libSDL-1.2.so.0
  NEEDED               libSDL_net-1.2.so.0
  NEEDED               libexpat.so.1
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               libc.so.6

Comment: Please Edit your post to add results, formatted correctly.

Comment: `objdump -p $(type -p scorched3d) | grep NEEDED | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 dpkg -S` to see what packages provide the needed libraries. No `sudo` needed.